# Inverting Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, maps, dictionary

I want to know which would be an efficient method to invert dictionaries in python. I also want to get rid of duplicate values by comparing the keys and choosing the larger over the smaller assuming they can be compared. Here is inverting a dictionary:

```
inverted = dict([[v,k] for k,v in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove duplicates by using the largest key, sort your dictionary iterator by value.  The call to dict will use the last key inserted:

```
import operator
inverted = dict((v,k) for k,v in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and direct implementation of inverting a dictionary and keeping the larger of any duplicate values:

```
inverted = {}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if v in inverted:
        inverted[v] = max(inverted[v], k)
    else:
        inverted[v] = k
```

This can be tightened-up a bit with *dict.get()*:

```
inverted = {}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    inverted[v] = max(inverted.get(v, k), k)
```

This code makes fewer comparisons and uses less memory than an approach using *sorted()*.

Comment: "I also want to get rid of duplicate values by comparing the keys and choosing the larger over the smaller assuming they can be compared."